# How can I calculate $ \sum\limits_{j=0}^{49}\binom{100}{2j+1}p^{100-(2j+1)} q^{2j+1} $?

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I got the following formula when I tried an exercise in probability:
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{49}\binom{100}{2j+1}p^{100-(2j+1)} q^{(2j+1)}
$$
where $p+q=1$. These are the "odd" terms in the expansion of $1=(p+q)^{100}$. I guess it might be $1/2$, but I don't have a proof. More generally, how can one simplify
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{(n/2)-1}\binom{n}{2j+1}p^{n-(2j+1)} q^{(2j+1)}
$$
when $n$ is even?

Comment: You could try putting $p=q$ [if you haven't already]

Comment: @rah4927 What for?

Comment: @Did,to guess the answer.But that might not work in this case,I think.

Comment: @rah4927 If "that does not work in this case", why indicate this dead-end to the OP?

Comment: @Did,a bit silly of me,really.But I thought it might be a good idea to plug in some trivial values and see the behaviour of the sum,hence the comment.

Comment: @Did,actually,rereading the OP's post,he probably did what I said and came up with the wrong answer $1/2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $$(p+q)^n=\sum_k{n\choose k}p^{n-k}q^k,$$ and $$(p-q)^n=\sum_k(-1)^k{n\choose k}p^{n-k}q^k,$$ hence $$1-(p-q)^n=(p+q)^n-(p-q)^n=2\sum_{k\ \text{odd}}\cdots$$